# I am not able to install a package (pyrealsense2)

Tags: package, ros, realsense

I am working on Visual Studio Code (Windows), on a ROS Terminal and I am trying to 'pip install pyrealsense2' but the following messages appear:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyrealsense2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrealsense2

I have my Intel RealSense 2.0 SDK downloaded (Intel RealSense Viewer) and was able to download all the SLAM packages (GMapping)

I tried to create a packege in Pypi but was not really able to enter my API token after 'twine upload dist/*'

Comment: pyrealsense2 is only supported up to the Python 3.7 versions. If you have a Python version above 3.8, consider using an older version.